# MIPS- How to Subtract (already used sub- does not work!)

Tags: mips

My code comes up with Unsupported R-Type, how do I make it subtract correctly. Tried changing other details within.... Already tried using subu...............................................................................................

```html
.data
str:  .asciiz "\nHello World!\n"
# You can change what is between the  quotes if you like

.text
.globl main

main:
# Do the addition
# For this, we first need to put the values
# to add into registers  ($t0 and $t1)
li $t0, 30    # You can change the 10
li $t1, 20    # You can change the 20

# Now we can add the values in $t0
# and $t1, putting the result in special register $a0
sub $a0, $t0, $t1

# Set up for printing the value in $a0.
# A 1 in $v0 means we want to print an int
li $v0, 1

# The system call looks at what is in $v0
# and $a0, and knows to print what is in $a0
syscall

# Now we want to print Hello World
# So we load the (address of the) string into $a0
la $a0, str

# And put a 4 in $v0 to mean print a string
li $v0, 4

# And just like before syscall looks at
# $v0 and $a0 and knows to print the string
syscall

# Nicely end the program
li $v0, 0
jr $ra
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program runs fine in the `mars` and `spim` simulators *except* for program termination. These simulators don't set up `$ra`, so it's zero. So, at the end, you're returning to something that may have semi-random instructions, including an illegal one. Thus, it's *not* your `sub` at all that is the problem. It's what happens later.

Change:

```
# Nicely end the program
li $v0, 0
jr $ra
```

Into:

```
# Nicely end the program
li $v0, 10
syscall
```